# How to find the IP of a Access Point

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a home network, using Belkin N750 as main router and wired ASUS RT-N12C1 which was set as AP mode. How can I find the IP of ASUS RT-N12C1 to change channel?

Answer (score 5):

If the IP address is statically defined in the AP, it will not show up in the DHCP tables in the router. If your router exposes an ARP table, it will likely be listed. If not, the simple (and tedious) way of hunting it down is to ping every IP address in the subnet until you find it. A tool like `nmap` can make this easier, and even tell you the MAC address for each device it finds and suggest the device's manufacturer.

If you have physical access to the AP (likely, assuming this is your own home network) and are not too concerned with the current settings, you can reset the device to factory (check the manual for instructions; its probably just holding the reset button for 10 seconds or similar) and then connect to it with the default, factory IP address (also in the manual).

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of would be to log into the main router and look through the DCHP tables to see the connected devices. If a name is displayed, it should then indicated which IP address you will need to navigate to.

Comment: I tried before but all IP indicated were other devices.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app on android / iOS caled FING. It's free, and gives a very quick scan of whatever wireless network it is on. It also has an option to scan open ports individually for each IP it finds. I use it all the time when installing pre-built headless (no screen/keyb) servers.

Scan once without AP, scan again with - and it highlights new addresses. Reset AP to factory settings if it has been set to a different IP range.

once reset, another way is to join the wireless network that the AP transmits, check your IP settings, look for the gateway, and browse to that address.

Answer (score 0):

Its Seems simple!
In windows Open My Computer.
in Left side navigation bar, select Network.
Wait for a while all the devices are in shown up in the list.

3 Type of device you can see there
1. computer/laptop/mobile
2. media server
3. Infrastructure

in infrastructure section you can see access point will be listed, see your manufacturer name and in property, you can find its IP.

Comment: I doubt you see it if your AP is in a different subnet, which can easily be the case.